# Checking array's elements are in another array in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two arrays. First array contains name(values) and it will search into another array and retrieve that data in result. My demo code is :

1st array-

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => CodeConfiguration
        [1] => TaxConfiguration
        [2] => ObjectAccountConfiguration
        [3] => RolePermission
    )
```

2nd array-

```
Array
(
    [submit] => 
    [CompanyID] => 1
    [BranchID] => 46
    [AccountID] => 60
    [CodeType_032] => 273
    [FixedCode] => IT1
    [SeriesFormat_033] => 375
    [SeriesConcateCharacter] => @
    [NumberLength] => 5
    [NumberPaddingCharacter] => 2
    [EffectiveFromDate] => 2014-02-01
    [EffectiveToDate] => 
    [ItemGroupID] => 1
    [TaxID] => 2
    [CalculationType_080] => 372
    [ObjectType] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [Code] => U
            [Name] => Uom
            [Description] => Uom
            [Group_077] => 309
            [SubGroup_078] => 324
            [RevisionNumber] => 6
            [DisplayName] => Uom
            [DefaultLedgerType_002] => 103
            [DefaultNarration_071] => 268
            [CopyTaxesFromParent] => 1
            [CheckPermissions] => 1
            [IsAdd] => 1
            [IsEdit] => 1
            [IsDelete] => 1
        )

    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ObjectType] => 12
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [CompanyID] => 1
                    [BranchID] => 46
                    [AccountID] => 60
                    [CodeType_032] => 273
                    [FixedCode] => IT1
                    [SeriesFormat_033] => 0
                    [SeriesConcateCharacter] => @
                    [NumberLength] => 5
                    [NumberPaddingCharacter] => 2
                    [EffectiveFromDate] => 2014-02-01
                    [EffectiveToDate] => 
                    [CreatedBy] => 
                    [ModifiedBy] => 22
                    [CreatedDate] => 
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-25 05:10:15
                    [RevisionNumber] => 6
                    [IsDirty] => 
                )

        )

    [ObjectAccountConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ObjectType] => 12
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [LineType_072] => 0
                    [ItemType_001] => 
                    [AccountType_003] => 
                    [LedgerType_002] => 
                    [ItemGroupID] => 
                    [TaxID] => 
                    [AccountID] => 
                    [BranchID] => 1
                    [SchemeID] => 
                    [LoyaltyID] => 
                    [CampaignID] => 
                    [CurrencyID] => 
                    [TaxGroupID] => 
                    [ContactType_011] => 
                    [ContactGroupID] => 
                    [CompanyID] => 1
                    [AccountMasterGroupID] => 
                    [CreatedBy] => 22
                    [ModifiedBy] => 22
                    [CreatedDate] => 2014-04-17 05:11:18
                    [ModifiedDate] => 2014-04-25 05:10:15
                    [RevisionNumber] => 5
                    [IsDirty] => 2
                )

        )

    [TaxConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                    [ItemGroupID] => 
                    [TaxID] => 
                    [CalculationType_080] => 372
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I want only search element from 1st array into 2nd array if it found then it retrieve data. So please suggest me an appropriate solution.

Comment: `array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1))` perhaps?

Comment: `My demo code is :` is where? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1));
```

Comment: You should have just copy-pasted it from the comments section ;-) no typos there.

Comment: @Jack Oh, so does it. Just posted the answer without see the comments :)

Comment: Try posting answers with your eyes closed for a change, more fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $array1item)
    $result[] = $array2[$array1item];
```